# Printing item of a dictionary syntax error

Tags: python, dictionary, printing

So this part of my code is creating trouble I suppose .

```
print '_'*10
print "NY State has :" cities['NY']
print 'OR State has :' cities['OR']
```

The error I get is given below .

```
File "ex39.py", line 25
    print "NY State has :" cities['NY']
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Everything seems to be correct then why I'm gettig this error , Pls help . Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you mean `"NY State has :" + cities['NY']`?

Comment: separate by a comma `print "NY State has :", cities['NY']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate elements of print by a comma

Example:

```
print '_'*10
print "NY State has :", cities['NY']
print 'OR State has :', cities['OR']
```

Comment: Thanks . I just overlooked I think

Answer (score 0):

Other option you have is to use .format

```
print '_'*10
print "NY State has : {}".format(cities['NY'])
print 'OR State has : {}'.format(cities['OR'])
```

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get you ?